# Haskell, docker: stack download failure

Tags: haskell, docker, haskell-stack

I've got a working docker image of haskell: https://hub.docker.com/r/fpco/stack-build/ . Untill today, that is. Any stack command in the project directory responds with this:

```
$ stack build
Downloading Docker-compatible stack executable
Control.Exception.Safe.throwString called with:

Could not get release information for Stack from: https://api.github.com/repos/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/tags/v1.6.1.1
Called from:
  throwString (src/Stack/Setup.hs:1768:14 in stack-1.6.1.1-LhZa5A6LsiS9SkA3QDJMKN:Stack.Setup
```

Google is not being very helpful. Any ideas? The fault is totally 'unprovoked': last yesterday's build was uneventful.

Comment: `v1.6.1` exists whereas `v1.6.1.1` doesn't exist. There might be a typo, bug ...

Comment: You've got a sharp eye! This is no typo. There is no `...src/Stack/Setup.hs` on my system. Line `1768` is also way too much. Is this really happening on my box?

Comment: I killed the docker daemon, and commented out docker support from `stack.yaml` of my project. It works now; curiously, still on container's versions of `ghci` and `ghc`. I can move on, but docker is there for a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably built `stack` from Hackage, where I uploaded 1.6.1.1 release that just makes it buildable with some newer dependencies.  This isn't a "real" new version of Stack (it has no user facing changes) so I didn't build new binaries for it or make a Github release, which means it couldn't find a docker-compatible binary that matched your version.  In the past, Stack would leave off the patchlevel when looking for such a binary, but looks like that functionality was lost at some point.  I actually noticed that myself a couple of days ago and fixed it in https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/commit/b33840102becbff9093865ef21368c9c5f66a309, which is included in the just-released stack-1.6.3.

Comment: You are right, probably. I just solved it minutes ago simply by `$ stack upgrade`. Got indeed `stack-1.6.3`. Thanks!